# Удаление значения из куки

Tags: jquery, cookie

Подскажите, как реализовать следующий механизм
Есть ссылка, кликая по которой мы получаем у родительского блока текстовые значения у спана с классом `name` и `price_per_unit`. А дальше у куки проверить есть ли значение совпадающие с текстовом значении спана с классом `name`, если есть то удалить это значение из куки.
Кука имеет следующую структуру

```
basket1:
   "["Текст","860"]"
basket2
   "["Книга","160"]"
```

Для работы с кукой использую след. библиотеку https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

```
$(document).on("click",".del", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var removeProduct = $(this).closest(".block").find("span.name").text();
    var removePrice = $(this).closest(".goods").find("span.price_per_unit").text();

   $(this).closest(".goods").hide();

   obj = document.cookie;
   for (var prop in obj) {
      if(obj == removeProduct) {
         obj = null;
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: А в чём то проблема? Ваш код не работает?

Comment: удаление конкретного значения не происходит

Comment: а где в вопросе использование библиотеки?

Comment: Может так: `$.cookie("name", null, { path: '/' })` или так `$.removeCookie('name', { path: '/' });` ? Не?

Comment: @Yuri, не, потому что в данном случае нет _$.cookie_ как и _$.removeCookie_

Comment: @ChromeChrome,  вы после того, как удалили значение из `obj` обратно вносите новое значение `obj` в `cookie`?

Comment: @Yuri, не понял вопроса. Вероятно он был адресован автору вопроса? :)

Comment: @Grundy, просто я не вижу, что бы он после удаления значения из `obj` обратно вносил его в куки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cookies = Cookies.get(); // получаем все куки (с помощью библиотеки js-cookie)
var value2remove = '["' + removeProduct + '","' + removePrice + '"]'; // собираем искомое значение в формате ["Продукт","цена"]

for (var cookie_name in cookies) { // перебираем все полученные куки
    if(cookies[cookie_name] == value2remove) // если это то самое значение - ...
        Cookies.remove(cookie_name); // удаляем куку по имени

    // если так и не удалит - раскомментить эту строчку и сверить значения,
    // т.к. я не уверен, что в полях "name" и "price_per_unit" лежат 
    // данные в корректном формате, и возможно понадобится над ними поколдовать

    //console.log(cookie_name, cookies[cookie_name], value2remove); 
}
```

Comment: твой вариант тоже не работает

Comment: ну тогда console.log в цикле, выводим проп и ремувпродукт, смотрим, правда ли они совпадают

Comment: и вообще, емнип, prop это будет индекс, а не значение.. ну консоле.лог все покажет

Comment: ну вопрос-то: как удалить? твой код - абсолютно ничего не удаляет из кук

Comment: это не мой код, я просто поменял переменную )))  а что доки по js-cookie на этот счет говорят?

Comment: это твой код, потому что сказал, что у автора опечатка, и привел, по твоему мнению - рабочий вариант. Но, что вариант автора, что твой - не работают, от слова никак, основная задача - удалить куку - не решена. Стоит либо отредактировать ответ либо удалить.

Comment: _что доки по js-cookie на этот счет говорят?_ - я не знаю почему автор вопрос упомянул эту библиотеку - в приведенном коде он ее не использует, поэтому нет смысла про нее говорить

Comment: ладно, давайте почитаем доку за автора :)  пофиксил ответ

Comment: Добавь пояснения что ты в этом коде делаешь

Comment: перемудрил... пофиксил еще раз, сорри...  а чего там пояснять, там все очевидно (теперь, по крайней мере)

Comment: Те кому очевидно, и вопрос бы не задали. Поэтому стоит хотя бы написать что именно ты делаешь и что за `Cookies`,  почему именно такое значение проверяешь _var value2remove = '["' + removeProduct + '","' + removePrice + '"]';_

Comment: ты как на экзамене валишь, я снова себя молодым студентом почувствовал :)))) ок, дописал -))

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой [jQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

**Подключение:**

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

**Установить куку:**

```
$.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });
```

**Удалить куку:**

```
$.removeCookie('name'); // => true
```

А по поводу корзинки, так лучше сделать массив из товаром и её уже писать в куки:

```
var items = [],
_cart = {};

_cart.add = function (item){
  $.each(items, function (index, cart_item){
     if (JSON.stringify(cart_item) == JSON.stringify(item)){
         items[index].qty++;
         _cart.renewCookieCart();
         return 'Item quantity has been improved';  
     }

     _cart.renewCookieCart();
     items.push(item);
     return 'Item has been added';
  });
}

_cart.remove = function (index){
    return items.splice(index, i);
}

_cart.renewCookieCart = function (){
   return $.cookie('basket', JSON.stringify(items));
}

_cart.getCart = function (){
   return JSON.parse($.cookie('basket'));
}
```

Comment: автор в вопросе указал, что он **уже** пользуется одной из библиотек для работы с куками. Зачем советовать ему другую?

Comment: @Grundy я предоставил полноценный ответ с альтернативным вариантом корзинки. Тут что-то плохого есть?